# Responsive CSS doesn't work

Tags: html, css

hello guys at stack overflow, I have a problem.
My responsive CSS for lower resolutions doesn't work, here is a example.

```
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 580px) {
.post_wrap_bg {
width: 460px;

height: 460px;
}
}
@media (min-width: 10px) and (max-width: 320px) {
.post_wrap_bg {
width: 360px;
height: 360px;
}
}
```

the >320 doesn't work, what could I possible have done wrong?

Comment: What does `doesn't work` mean? What is the desired and the actual behavior?

Comment: It means that it still uses the CSS from the higher resolutions

Comment: So you also have CSS for higher than 580px?

Comment: By the way, you have a flaw: when the width is exactly 320px, which media query should be used? Both match 320px.

Comment: The spelling errors were already correct in the CSS file, that's not the problem

Comment: Yes I have CSS for higher resolutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try like this,

```
@media (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 580px) {
  .post_wrap_bg {
    width: 460px;
    height: 460px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 10px) and (max-width: 320px) {
  .post_wrap_bg {
    width: 360px;
    height: 360px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have a typo:

```
widht: 460px;
```

Should be

```
width: 460px;
```

Fix it and it will work as expected.

Comment: Twice even. In both queries.

Comment: Also change the limts of the media queries to **not** overlap (i.e `320` width overlaps in both queries)